# How to get unread messages from gmail through secure social

Tags: message, playframework-2.1, inbox, securesocial

I am play application developer. I used secure social to login into my application. I got username, email id, first name and last name through secure social. I want to get unread message of logged in user gmail inbox. how to get that. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're a Scala developer then having a look at this GitHub repo should help you on your way. It has a working implementation of integrating Securesocial authentication with accessing a Gmail inbox.

https://github.com/dr3s/pimly/tree/master/pimly-gmail

Two points:

- You need a way to convert your OAuth2 authorisation to something IMAP can use (SASL)
- You can use the java mail API to interact with IMAP email messages